# Regex from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I Want to know if there is a tool for converting JavaScript Regex to PHP.

I got the following Regex in JAvascript

```
 var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

And

```
 pwbx2.match(/.[^!,+,§,\),\(,=,\-,\.,:,,,\w]/)
```

Now I wan't to match the given values to check also at the server side on this regex. How can i do it?

Cheers

Sven

Comment: why cant you use ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: because i don't understand this manual site. I also looked it up, but, I don't get, what it want me to tell.

Comment: In PHP you can validate an email with: `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Yes!! Don't waste your time custom-building a complicated regex which is almost certain to be wrong for some use cases. Use `filter_var()`.

Comment: But anyway, using the same pattern with `preg_match()` requires single-quoting around it (PHP doesn't have regex literals)  `$true_or_false = preg_match('/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,...restofpattern$/', $input);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte To be fair, `filter_var` doesn't cover *all* the use cases one may encounter.

Comment: @MaxArt: Indeed, but it is the best compromise (between `[^\s@]+@\S+` and a one page long pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know that `.[^!,+,§,\),\(,=,\-,\.,:,,,\w]` is a monstrosity. In normal regex, this would be:

```
.[^-.,:+=!§()\w]
```

The `[brackets]` indicate a character class. They mean "match one character in this class," or, when the first charcter is `^` "match one character that is not in this class." So there is never any need to repeat a character in a character class. This one has eleven commas!

Your test could be expressed in this compact fashion:

```
$theregex = '~.[^-.,:+=!§()\w]~';
echo (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring)) ? "**It Matches!**" : "Nah... No match." ;
```

**But that probably doesn't work the way you want anyway**

The original regex begs the question: what where they thinking when they wrote this? Clearly whoever wrote this was regex-illiterate (and I don't mean to be gratuitously condescending... that's just a fact.) Therefore, it is quite likely that they had something quite different in mind when they wrote it. And if that's a case, it doesn't matter how well you translate it: it won't do the job it was intended for.

If you know what the regex is supposed to do, tell us, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input, after a One Day Test i found this to match everything i want. `$pattern = '/.[^!\+\§\)\(=\.\-:,a-zA-Z0-9]/';` If i just make `$pattern = '/.[^!+§)(=.-:,a-zA-Z0-9]/';` it kills the wrong stuff

Answer (score 1):

you can use preg_match like this :

```
 $pattern="/.[^-.,:+=!§()\w]/";
 $string="your string to match";
 if( preg_match($pattern,$string) != 1){
    echo "nothing found";
 }else{
    echo "found";
 }
```

Comment: Why don't he echo nothing found if i put a string wit an '_' in it?

Comment: I won't downvote you, but please fix `[^!,+,§,\),\(,=,\-,\.,:,,,\w]`. That's unacceptable regex for an accepted answer. :)